# RHEL7.7からWindows Server 2016の共有フォルダをマウントできない

Tags: linux, rhel, windows-server

表題の件、以下のエラーが発生してしまいWindows Server 2016の共有フォルダをマウントができません。

**環境**
Windows Server 2016
RHEL 7.7

**実行コマンド**

```
mount -t cifs //XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXX/XXX_test /root/work/cifs \
    -o username=XXXX_testuser,password=XXXXX,sec="ntlmv2",vers="2.1"
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```
mount error(13):Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

以下、原因になりそうなところは設定確認しております。

・共有フォルダへのアクセス権設定用のWindowsアカウントを個別に設定
・対象のWindowsアカウントに共有フォルダへのアクセス権を設定
・共有の設定権限(フルコントロール)を付与
・sambaで利用されるポート445を開放
・CIFS、SMBをインストール
・secオプションの指定

ネット等で同事象をしらべていたのですが、問題解決には至らずこちらに質問させていただきました。

Answer (score 1):

私の環境は、Windows10の共有フォルダに対して、Ubuntu 20.04 LTSから見に行こうとして、同じコマンドで同じエラー（それ以外もエラーあり）で半日悩んで、今解決したのですが、下記のサイトをよく見ると "samba-clientとcifs-utilsはインストールしていない" とはっきり書いてありました。

[Ubuntuからwindowsの共有フォルダにアクセスする。](https://www.khstasaba.com/?p=862)

それらを私は入れていたため、削除しました。

```
$ sudo apt remove samba-client
$ sudo apt remove cifs-utils
```

そうしたら、`mount` コマンドがエラー出ることなく実行できました。
Windowsの共有フォルダもばっちり見れました。

Answer (score -1):

> mount error(13):Permission denied
> Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

原因はわかりませんが、次のようにオプションを変更してみて接続できるか確認してみてください。

## ユーザ名、ドメイン、パスワードの指定方法を変える

- `username=USERNAME,password=PASSWORD,domain=DOMAIN`
- `username=DOMAIN/USERNAME,password=PASSWORD`
- `username=DOMAIN/USERNAME%PASSWORD`

## プロトコルバージョンを変更

- `vers=1.0`
- `vers=2.0`
- `vers=3.0`

## セキュリティモードを変える

- `sec=none`
- `sec=krb5`
- `sec=krb5i`
- `sec=ntlm`
- `sec=ntlmi`
- `sec=ntlmv2`
- `sec=ntlmv2i`
- `sec=ntlmssp`
- `sec=ntlmsspi`

経験則ですが、Windowsのバージョンや、ドメインかワークグループか、Windows Updateが行われているか、などで必要なオプションが変わるようです。また、Windows Update後の「再起動待ち」状態の場合に、接続できないことがありました。可能なら 念の為 Windows Serverを一度再起動してみるのも良いかもしれません。